# html form submit post content executed

Tags: forms, post, href

My code contains an HTML form post action  with a text area and submit button.

When I give an a tag with reference link in this text area, the form submission fails. It is redirected to the home page. If anyone know the reason, please help me.

Also ,img tag are redirected to home page

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: <html>

<body>


<form action="test2.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>

 <textarea name="t1" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>

</td></tr>
<tr>
    <td width="0%"><input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Proceed"></td>
    <td >&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

</table>
</form>
<body>


</html>

Comment: can you please add it into your post. Its hard to understand as a text